# Syntax for Redis EVAL calling ZRANGEBYSCORE with LIMIT option

Tags: lua, redis

How can I pass the LIMIT option to an [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval) Redis Command calling [ZRANGEBYSCORE](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) command?

For a simple command like SET the syntax is the following

```
eval "return redis.call('set',KEYS[1],'bar')" 1 foo
```

In my case the LUA script would be something along the lines of

```
eval "return redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE',KEYS[1],ARGV[1],ARGV[2])" 2 foo bar 0 +inf
```

But how can I pass values to the LIMIT option inside this call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a `LIMIT` of 123 (offset) and 456 (count), the following should work for:

```
eval "return redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE',KEYS[1],ARGV[1],ARGV[2],'LIMIT',ARGV[3],ARGV[4])" 2 foo bar 0 +inf 123 456
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks ! Even understood the logic behind enumerating keys and arguments, in fact I could just do `eval "..." 1 foo 0 +inf 123 456` with a single key (without bar)

Comment: Indeed - bar isn't needed as you're not accessing `KEYS[2]` :)